# Notification or report for security problem of unix systems?

Tags: exploit, known-vulnerabilities, unix, security-theater, patching

I have Unix systems (Solaris, Oracle,.Redhat etc.). I have to control all systems for security problem,bugs,patch,vulnerabilities.

I'm looking for security information for all security issues.

After that I'll update and check  all  Unix systems.
I need to take notification  for Unix systems or I need admin panel for manage system.
When I searched the web, I found this site: `securitytracker.com` which sends email notifications for vulnerabilities. Also I need report for latest vulnerabilities, patch and other systems.

Is there any commercial/free alternative to ^securitytracker.com`?

How can I manage this sytems for latest vulnerabilities? Is there any recommendation for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the services we use to track vulnerabilities is called [Cassandra](https://cassandra.cerias.purdue.edu/main/index.html).

You create a profile and then tell it what servers and software you are using and it sends you notifications of vulnerabilities.

Comment: Also I have recently made an App which might help you to get vulnerability notifications, https://itunes.apple.com/au/app/vulhunter/id742110071?mt=8

Comment: I did something similar to get alerts and notifications for vulnerabilities for the software/libraries on your server/webapp with https://secureit.io - I built it for that purpose.

At the moment it is completely free, and it will be for as long as it will be in Beta, but in the future I'll make it as accessible as I can, I'm even considering 'donationware' to run it. And at the moment the best donation you can give me in case you like it is to tell me what you think of it and how I can make it better.